# Starting intent in an extra WebView class instead in an inner class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview

I wanted to keep my MainActivity small and clear. So I have created **an seperate class** for WebView **instead of an inner class** this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

But now I wanted to start a new activity in `CustomWebViewClient` with the `openInAppBrowser` method:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(PROJECT_REMOTE)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            openInAppBrowser(this, url);
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void openInAppBrowser(Activity activity, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, InAppBrowser.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Since `this` and `MainActivity.this` won't work here, how could I reference the MainActivity to make this method work? Or is the inner class inside the MainActivity the better or only option?

Comment: Is webview in main activity class ?

Comment: Yes, I create a new CustomWebViewClient instance (the first code I posted) in MainActivity.

Comment: Then `MainActivity.this` doesn't work?

Comment: With `MainActivity.this` it says that MainActivity is not an enclosing class.

Comment: Here pass `openInAppBrowser(MainActivity.this, url);`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7sGYAe1.jpg

Comment: How about make a constructor passing in the activity like mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(this));  then inside CustomWebViewClient class you can use it.

Comment: @kggoh Could you post an example as answer?

Comment: as requested, just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(this)); 



public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

Activity activity;

public CustomWebViewClient (Activity activity) {
    this.activity= activity;

}

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(PROJECT_REMOTE)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            openInAppBrowser(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void openInAppBrowser(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, InAppBrowser.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

As requested. I am not sure this will work, that's why I did not put on answer in the first place.